# PMD blocker is not visible on eclipse IDE as plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, pmd, sonarlint

I have exported the PMD bug rule xml file from SonarQube server, same I have imported after installing eclipse pmd plugin for eclipse IDE.

All is fine and I can see the PMD problems in marker view.

But I have found a mis match i.e. for a statment as following, it is showing blocker(`null has passsed for Non null parameter`) in SonarQubeServer but no any error in SonarLint.

Although it is showing all other PMD problems same as SonarQube in that class.

```
getMisMatchInPMDRule(CrationXXX cre, ByuInXXXX by, Double xx, Double xx)
```

Is there any thing I have done wrong while importing?

Answer (score 1):

SonarLint report issues only from SonarSource analyzer. For java only issues from SonarJava will be reported. 
PMD and findbugs have their own plugins for Eclipse.

Comment: yeah i know,  I have installed seprate pmd plugin in eclipse and imported the rule xml file which I exported from SonarQube server as SonarQube server supports external plugin